# Пр нажатии на ссылку якорь, смещается таблица

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте!

Сайт  сверстан на bootstrap. В верхней части сайта находится хедер, который закреплен (всегда там остается при прокрутки страницы).

Проблема:
В хедере имеются ссылки-якори на определенную позицию. При нажатии на ссылку, она переводит на позицию, но отступ заданный

> body.fixed-nav

Не срабатывает и получается, что ссылка-якорь указана верно, но позиция показывается не та(т.к. таблица уходит под хедер).

Как это исправить? спасибо.

Comment: покопавшись в инспекторе я увидел, что вы используете данный плагин https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav, там в доккумменации написано, что можно использовать offset.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что `.container` в котором весь контент - начинается от самого верха. Стоит дать отступ для него. или по другому сверстать меню + контент

Comment: @xAqweRx, то есть задать ему margin-top?

Comment: Грубо говоря - да. Задать `margin-top` как быстрый способ решения вопроса. Но концептуально это не правильно